# Перенос значений переменной из js в php

Tags: php, javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
      var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    });
  }
</script>

<?php
    if (isset($_GET['u_name'])) {
        echo "Значение JavaScript-переменной: ". $_GET['u_name'];
    } else {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
        echo 'document.location.href="' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . '?u_name=" +longitude';
        echo '</script>';
        exit();
    }
?>
```

Почему ничего не выводится?

Answer (score 1):

Вы не не передаете координаты в `get` параметры потому и не работает.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
      var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
      
      //если нет гет параметров обновляем страницу и добавляем их
      if (location.href.indexOf('lat')==-1){
                window.location.href = location.href + "?lat=" + latitude + "&lon=" + longitude;
            }
            
    });
  }
</script>

<?php
    if (isset($_GET['lat'])) {
        echo "Значение JavaScript-переменной latitude: ". $_GET['lat'];
         echo "Значение JavaScript-переменной longitude: ". $_GET['lon'];
    } 
?>
```